# What is the full form of "The whole management structure" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

What is the full/sentence form of the phrase “The whole management structure"? IF THERE HAD BEEN the whole management structure?

Perhaps the group’s structure accounted for its success. Were its members pursuing well-defined and laudable goals? The group leader, Tom West, offered the precept that “not everything worth doing is worth doing well.” Pushed to translate his maxim, he elaborated,“If you can do a quick-and-dirty job and it works, do it”(p. 119). Did the group have clear and well-coordinated roles and relationships? According to Kidder, it kept no meaningful charts, graphs, or organization tables. One of the group’s engineers put it bluntly: “The whole management structure—anyone in Harvard Business School would
have barfed”(p. 116).

Source:https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=nz2DpJLJDSoC&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=Perhaps+the+group%E2%80%99s+structure+accounted+for+its+success.+Were+its+members+pursuing+well-defined+and+laudable+goals?+The+group+leader,+Tom+West,+offered+the+precept+that+%E2%80%9Cnot+everything+worth+doing+is+worth+doing+well.%E2%80%9D+Pushed+to+translate+his+maxim,+he+elaborated,%E2%80%9CIf+you+can+do+a+quick-and-dirty+job+and+it+works,+do+it%E2%80%9D(p.+119).+Did+the+group+have+clear+and+well-coordinated+roles+and+relationships?+According+to+Kidder,+it+kept+no+meaningful+charts,+graphs,+or+organization+tables.+One+of+the+group%E2%80%99s+engineers+put+it+bluntly:%E2%80%9CThe+whole+management+structure%E2%80%94anyone+in+Harvard+Business+School+would+have+barfed%E2%80%9D(p.+116).&source=bl&ots=Il1wCQhoER&sig=ACfU3U1gG6ZNNWahARGvagUWunMcTZV4ug&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMudvo5efhAhWpUN4KHQegBY8Q6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=Perhaps%20the%20group%E2%80%99s%20structure%20accounted%20for%20its%20success.%20Were%20its%20members%20pursuing%20well-defined%20and%20laudable%20goals%3F%20The%20group%20leader%2C%20Tom%20West%2C%20offered%20the%20precept%20that%20%E2%80%9Cnot%20everything%20worth%20doing%20is%20worth%20doing%20well.%E2%80%9D%20Pushed%20to%20translate%20his%20maxim%2C%20he%20elaborated%2C%E2%80%9CIf%20you%20can%20do%20a%20quick-and-dirty%20job%20and%20it%20works%2C%20do%20it%E2%80%9D(p.%20119).%20Did%20the%20group%20have%20clear%20and%20well-coordinated%20roles%20and%20relationships%3F%20According%20to%20Kidder%2C%20it%20kept%20no%20meaningful%20charts%2C%20graphs%2C%20or%20organization%20tables.%20One%20of%20the%20group%E2%80%99s%20engineers%20put%20it%20bluntly%3A%E2%80%9CThe%20whole%20management%20structure%E2%80%94anyone%20in%20Harvard%20Business%20School%20would%20have%20barfed%E2%80%9D(p.%20116).&f=false

Comment: Please clean up your question so that it is legible. Turn *source* into a hyperlink—don't just paste the entire URL into the text. (I've corrected this for you several times in the past, so you can refer to those questions to guide you—or you can refer to [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a topic-comment sentence, which isn't a very common form in English, but the meaning is straightforward.  The topic is "the whole management structure" and the comment is "anyone (thinking about it) in Harvard Business School would have barfed."  It's a spoken form that probably occurs when people start a sentence with a noun phrase that could be the subject, and then complete the thought with a sentence where the noun phrase can't be the subject:

- That pass--no one else could have caught it!
- The color of that dress--what was she thinking?

When writing, the opportunity to edit would let you rephrase as:

- No one else could have caught that pass!
- What was she thinking when she chose a dress that color?